# Desktop sounds on smartphone

Tags: music, windows-mobile

I'm wondering if it's possible to *play* music files on my desktop but *send* the audio not to my desktop speakers but (i.e. using BlueTooth) to my smartphone's speaker?

That way I could just play all my music on my desktop and walk around with my phone and headset in the house when doing all kinds of stuff. ( mostly cleaning =/ )

Additional info:

--
OS: Ubuntu and Windows 7
Phone: HTC Touch HD

Comment: I'm curious why nobody mentioned [icecast](http://www.icecast.org/)?

Comment: I'm wondering how exactly this would apply to my question since i never heard about icecast and this is what the FAQ says: *Icecast is a collection of programs and libraries for streaming audio over the Internet.*  Do you mean i should stream my music on their servers and use my phone to receive the music stream from their server?

Answer (score 1):

Only if your smartphone provided audio playback services (like a headset does), and as smartphones are devices that you connect headsets to, and not connect to other things as headsets I can't see any right minded smartphone manufacturer providing that facility. (It'd be only used by one person in a million, and not worth investing the time & money in implementing it).

Comment: One possible thought.... No one has written a jack endpoint for Android have they?

Comment: Actually, some smartphones may be used as handsets for Skype, so functionality may be there.

Comment: Mine can - by installing Skype onto the phone.  Propriatory (sp?) software.  The only solution I could think of would be porting something like Jack to Android which, as far as I can tell, hasn't been done.  The questor specifically mentioned using BlueTooth, so the answer would still be no ;)

Comment: Please note that my HTC doesn't run Android but Windows Mobile. I also mentioned BlueTooth since i don't really know *that* much about data transfer from/to smartphones. But technically, isn't this possible: redirect audio stream using some data transfer to my phone, phone receives audio stream and plays it. (of course somebody would still have to implement this) I don't know much about codecs etc. (that's what i'm going to see this year in class) but i can figure there are some bottle-necks there too...

Comment: Technically, yes it's possible.  That's why I was wondering if Jack had been ported (Jack is a network audio protocol used mainly under Linux but is available for Windows etc - http://jackaudio.org/ )  [Sorry about the Android confusion - I have a HTC phone and it runs Android]